# How to copy user rights and roles from one user to another

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, role, copy

I require a PL/SQL script that copies all of a user's rights, roles and mandates from one user to another.

I am using Oracle 12c.

Comment: I answered this on stackoverflow.com and you are asking it again.

Answer (score 1):

may be helpful.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('ROLE_GRANT','username') FROM DUAL;
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('SYSTEM_GRANT','username') FROM DUAL;

set long 9999999
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_GRANTED_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT','username') FROM DUAL;
```